# DocuSign: Redirect URI is not registered properly error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make an authorization request and I'm receiving the error:

> Redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign

**This is the URL I'm using:**

> https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://1.11.111.111/auth/callback?secret=XXXXXXXXX

**This is the redirect URI I registered, matching the URL above:**

[image]

**This is the error:**

[image]

The client_id matches the integrator key.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Do not include any of the query parameters when you are configuring the Redirect URI(s) through your DocuSign account. So instead of this

```
http://1.11.111.111/auth/callback?secret=XXXXXXXXX
```

It should be

```
http://1.11.111.111/auth/callback
```

Note that redirect URIs are case-sensitive so make sure you also are matching it exactly.

Comment: Oh I tried that...and about every other combination. I ended up temporarily not requiring a secret for the authorization. Still really annoying that it didn't work with a secret.

Comment: My tests are working with a secret, are you sure you were using a secret that was generated on the Integrator Key that you are using in your tests?  Have you tried generating a new secret under your current key to see if that works?  Otherwise not exactly sure why it wouldn't be working for you.